# Flux across the semisphere of $F=(xy, -xy, z\sin^2ze^{x^2+y^2})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-theorem

I'm asked to find the flux (going out) of the upper-unitary-semisphere of the following vector field:
$$F=(xy, -xy, z\sin^2ze^{x^2+y^2})$$
Every component is $C^{\infty}$ so we can apply the divergence theorem. We obtain:
$$\int_S F\times n d\Sigma=\int_S div(F)dV$$
so we have to compute:
$$\int_S y-x+e^{x^2+y^2}(\sin^2z+2z\sin z\cos z)dxdydz$$
or at least I need to say it's positive.
I'd like to see a fast computation of this integral, any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.